# cracked across the ridge

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "cracked" mean in the following example sentence?

> A shot cracked across the ridge.

Does the "cracked" mean making a sudden explosive sound or doing so while moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the sudden explosive sound, and the hearer's impression of the movement of the sound.
Of course, sound always moves at about 760 mph, but the expression suggests a subjective impression of motion that may be the result of reverberation from physical terrain features, like the ridge.